# Inserting a row in Excel yields a new row in different worksheet. How do I stop this?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I "inherited" a complex Excel workbook that I now need to update (without breaking).

I have 2 worksheets (tabs at the bottom) that reference each other in formulas, et al.  Formulas make sense to me, so I have no problem with this.

What is strange is that whenever I hide/unhide rows/columns, or add/remove rows from either worksheet, the changes are reflected in the other sheet.

In other words, if I have:

```
1:  Foo   Bar
2:  Bar   Baz
3:  Ho    Ge
```

as 3 rows in one sheet, when I highlight row 3 and "Insert Row", I get a new, blank row above `3` as expected.  Then, when I navigate to the other sheet, I get new rows there.

I would like to "delink" these sheets.  Any ideas what could be the trouble here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have selected both sheets.  Insert/Delete etc. are applied to all selected worksheets.  Please make sure only one sheet is selected (by clicking Sheet1 / Sheet2 randomly or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd>.

This pic shows Sheet1 and Sheet2 selected but not Sheet3.
[image: Selection of Worksheets]

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if this is the right answer, as my problem with that sheet seems to have magically disappeared -- but I assume this was probably it!